# GWT: Super Dev Mode - Compile button missing when I press 'Dev Mode On'

Tags: gwt, gwt-super-dev-mode

I am attempting to setup GWT's super dev mode but am running into an issue.  Here is where I am at:

- GWT 2.5.0
- Tomcat server deployed on a Virtual Machine say.  To run my application, I navigate to: `http://myVirtualMachine/myApplication`.
- Code server on local dev machine.  Running on `http://localhost:12345`.  Bookmarked the `Dev Mode On` and `Dev Mode Off` bookmarklets
- I have added the following to the `<module>` section of my myModule.gwt.xml file:

  ```
  <add-linker name="xsiframe"/>
  <set-configuration-property name="devModeRedirectEnabled" value="true"/>
  <set-property name="compiler.useSourceMaps" value="true"/>
  <set-configuration-property name="devModeUrlWhitelistRegexp" value="http://.*" />
  ```
- Recomile webapp and deploy to myVirtualMachine
- Restart code server
- Go to `http://myVirtualMachine/myApplication`, click `Dev Mode On` bookmarklet.

I am expecting to get a popup that looks like this:

```
Choose a module to recompile: 
                  ---------
1. someName      |compile|
                  ---------
```

I am getting this instead:

```
Choose a module to recompile: 

1. someName
```

The compile button is missing.  Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: GWT 2.7.0 has a lot of improvements using Super Dev Mode. With the current GWT Eclipse Plugin it is quite easy to start Super Dev Mode. Why are you using the old version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason should be set as a "title" on the module name: hover over it to have it displayed.

Source: https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+/2.5.0/dev/codeserver/java/com/google/gwt/dev/codeserver/dev_mode_on.js